# Jenkins Workflow Parallel step and closures

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to run a few suits with tests in parallel as a part of workflow. So I create a map, put there a couple of closures and pass it to parallel step. The issue that I'm facing related to name of the HTML report. After execution, I see a few identical "HTML Report" links, so I can't open specific report - all of them have the same name. I had tried to make this name unique, but these attempts were not successful. Does anyone faced similar thing?

```
def testExecutions = [:]

def testExecution = {
   node {
        //code to run tests

        publishHTML(target: [allowMissing: false, 
                             alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, 
                             keepAll: true, reportDir: 'target/reports', 
                             reportFiles: 'index.html', 
                             reportName: "HTML Report " + it)
   }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    final k = i

    testExecutions.put("tests $k", {testExecution(k)})
}

parallel(testExecutions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the testExecution() function lacks the `it` parameter?

```
def testExecution(it) = {
    node {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it is implicit parameter - [Implicit parameter](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your node is on the wrong level. Now this rises a really interesting question.

My guess would be that **when** your workers would actually get the node to execute k or it would have be already evaluated by the master, meaning that from the point of view of parallel call the closure implicit argument would always be equal to 1. (although I consider myself not educated enough with Jenkins workflow and groovy to say for sure)

This version should work for you

```
def testExecutions = [:]

def testExecution = {
    println "HTML Report " + it
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    final k = i

    testExecutions.put("tests $k", {node{testExecution(k)}})
}

parallel(testExecutions)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the case when there is just 'println' command. However, if first of all tests executed and then report is generated, it gets "HMTL Report 1" name for both cases. Probably it is because the evaluation of k. I ended up adding time stampt to report name